# Code cloned to the incorrect folder

Tags: git

I cloned the master branch using Git onto a folder I created in the Desktop. Later on, I realized that's not where I want it to be and moved it to a folder in my C drive. I didn't realize that Git might throw errors until I opened it and saw that it says that the repo isn't in the place that I originally put it in. Is there a way to solve this and tell Git that I want the cloned repo in the C drive where I moved it to?

Apologies if the question seems silly. I am very new to Git and I want to learn this as quickly and efficiently as I can.

Thanks!

Comment: Git doesn't care where the project directory is. What program are you using? Git Bash shouldn't give you problems.

Comment: What's the exact error you're getting?

Comment: Im sorry but i closed it and not able to reproduce it again...its basically this--i cloned the repo onto a folder and later moved that folder to a different location. Now i want Git to be able to recognize it..

Comment: Did you also copy the .git folder? If you don't have show hidden items on in Explorer, you wont see it.

Comment: @BrianRacker The error you're seeing in SourceTree is probably just saying the bookmark on the left-hand bar isn't found anymore. Double-clicking it will let you specify where you moved it to, or just dragging the folder back into SourceTree will add it again as a new bookmark. I voted to close though, since this is more an issue with user-interface in SourceTree that can't be reproduced now.

Answer (score 0):

> Im sorry but i closed it and not able to reproduce it again...
>
> its basically this--i cloned the repo onto a folder and later moved that folder to a different location.
>
> Now i want Git to be able to recognize it

1. Open source tree
2. Click on Clone / New
3. Choose the tab - **Add Working copy**
4. Choose the folder where you have have moved git to.

[image]